# EL template no recibe las variables del get_context_data

Tags: django, django-templates, context

estoy teniendo problemas con mi proyecto, tengo redefinido en la vista el metodo get_context_data, en el cual tengo una variable context['report_ph_mes'] = self.get_report_ph_mes(). La funcion a la q la igualo devuelve un array donde cada posicion corresponde a un mes del año. Al pasar la variable al Template asignado en mi vista no muestra nada, como si no le pasara nada.

En el view.py

```
    def get_contex_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super.get_contex_data()
      context['report_ph_mes'] = self.get_report_ph_mes()
    return context
```

Le tengo puesto un print para ver si esta trabajando bien y me devuelve

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]

En el template.html

```
<script>
            var ph_year = '{{ report_ph_mes|safe }}';
            console.log(ph_year)
            ....
            var series_column = "[{'data': {{ report_ph_mes|safe }}, 'name': 'X'}]";
            console.log(series_column)
            $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#graf_column').highcharts({
                    ....
                    series: JSON.parse(series_column.replace(/'/g,'\"'))
                  });
                });
        </script>
```

El console.log(series_column) me devuelve

[{'data':  , 'name': 'Phishing URLs'}]

Como verán no me esta reconociendo la variable desp {{ report_ph_mes|safe }}....alguna idea de que puede ser?? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es por que esta mal nombrado, no es get_contex_data, es get_context_data(). Debe de ir así:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(MiView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['report_ph_mes'] = self.get_report_ph_mes()
    return context
```

Donde MiView es el nombre del CBV donde estas sobrescribiendo el método get_context_data()

De esta manera ya debería de devolverte el valor al template.

Comment: Si me di cuenta en la noche. Perdon x el absurdo error d novato. Una pregunta @KevinRamirezZavalza, q tenga redefinido el metodo safe en el modelo influye a la hora de ejecutar un editar sobre un objeto del mismo modelo???

Comment: Si modificas el método save() dentro de tu modelo afectara tanto creación como edición a menos que el método save() identifique si es creación o edición y especifiques que hacer para cada caso. Si tienes una duda con respecto a esto te invito a realizar una nueva pregunta, esta podría ayudar a alguien mas.

Comment: El problemas es que al editar un registro existente me da error porque ya existe el id de esa instancia, es como si quisiera insertarlo de nuevo y no editarlo. En mi save del modelo tngo redefinido los valores q tomara cada atributo de la nueva instancia por metodos en especifico